# Operating on lists by grouped property values

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class with the following structure:

```
class Test 
{    
    int Value { get; set; }
    List<string> Categories { get; set }
}
```

I want to do operations on sets grouped by their tag, such as:

```
List<Test> myData = new List<Test>{ add n items };

myData.GroupBy(x => x.Categories ).Count(); // I know this wont work
```

What I want to achieve is being able to do operations on a set which matches a predicate, and then return the values of that set. Ideally I would like to have a container class of sorts:

```
class Metrics 
{    
    int Max { get; set; }
    int Min { get; set; }
    double Avg { get; set; }
    double Mode { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like this (semi pseudo code)

```
Dictionary<string, Metrics> result = new Dictionary<string, Metrics>();

// find all unique categories across all my items in the list and then
foreach(string category in myData.Categories)
{    
   if(Tag not exists in result)
   {
       results.Add(category, new Metrics
       {
            Max = myData.GroupBy(x => x.Categories == category).Max,
            Avg = myData.GroupBy(x => x.Categories == category).Average()
       }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: `Tag` or `Tags` ?  The naming and usage are conflicting with the `List<string>` type.

Comment: Ah my bad. didn't realize there was a class called Tag, it was merely the mental idea I had that I would have string value(s) tagging/defining which category the class data would belong to. Edited the post to reflect that it's not a Tag class per se.

Comment: Still the same problem... It's about the 's' in `x.Categories == category`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to a collection of flattened anonymous objects:

```
myData.SelectMany(item => item.Categories.Select(category => new { Category = category, Item = item}))
      .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
      .Where(/* The predicates you want to do */
```

Since your later queries seem to be aggregations on the amount of each tag you can also add another `Select` after the `GroupBy` to make later aggregations simpler:

```
.Select(grouping => new 
{ 
    Tag = grouping.Key,
    Amount = grouping.Count(),
    Items = grouping.Select(item => item.Item)
})
```